# My difficulties with regard to estimation of parameters using genetic algorithms in R language

Tags: r, genetic-algorithms

*** I just came to know that the post was unlocked, meanwhile I have re-posted the question on this forum. But I am posting the edited version here as well as I am unaware of the rules in this regard. ***

1. I have a function $$F(t) = a\frac{1 – e^{-(b+c)t}}{1 + \frac{c}{b}e^{-(b+c)t}}\space .$$ This equation has a sigmoidal shape and without multiple local optima. I have values of $F(t)$ for certain discrete values of $t$. I have used the Nonlinear Least Squares to estimate the $a, b,$ and $ c $ parameters based on this data. It is reported in the relevant literature (business management) that in the absence of adequate data (small number of data points). Genetic algorithm [(GA)](https://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/), a heuristic search, does a better job of estimating $a, b, c$ than other methods. It is in this context that I am trying to use GA to estimate $a, b, c$. I am using the GA package in the R programming language to estimate them. The parameters $b$ and $c$ in theory are known to vary thus: $b=[0,1]; c=[0, \infty)$. However, the available literature suggests that $b$ and $c$ vary within much tighter bounds in real life. When I use these smaller bounds in the max and min arguments of the ga() function in R language, the estimates are heavily dependent on the values that I set as max and min. For instance, if I set $c$ as min$(c) = 0$, max$(c) = 0.2$, $c$ might be estimated as $0.1995$. This is my experience on most occasions. On the other hand, if I set $b=[0,1]$ and $c = [0, \infty)$, then the estimates deviate from the values as cited in the literature, although they do not remain very close to the initial max or min values that I set. My question is: How can I escape both these (the dependence on max, min that I set and the deviation from literature values). **Q: Please guide me as to how to tune parameters such as mutation rate that are the considerations in this regard.**
2. The parameters $b$ and $c$ are expected to approximate a normal distribution, according to the extant literature. To test this, I have certain ratios of $c/b;$ say $=2, 4, 6$. I use an error term for $F(t)$ assuming that the error term follows a normal distribution with variances $0.12, 0.18, 0.24, 0.30$. Thus there are $3*4=12$ combinations for the $c/b$ ratio and error variance. I simulate $b$ and $c$ for these 12 combinations using the data I have, using the `rnorm()` function. I would use this to see whether $b$ and $c$ indeed follow the normal distribution. In this attempt, however, the initial limits set in terms of max and min arguments of the `ga()` function in R-language again heavily influence the estimates of $b$ and $c$ as described in 1, above.

I tried to describe the problem to the best of my ability. I expect the community to guide me if any further clarification is required. The literature that I talked about uses a commercially available software package and not R.

---

@Paul: Sir, thank you for your answer.

1. Since I used various values for the min and max arguments of parameters in the ga() function, and 2 of a, b and c almost always are close to the limits set, I do not think the parameters near there explain the data better.
2. Conventional wisdom parameters are not inaccurate, as they have been tested on various data for a number of years.
3. Data can be an issue, but one has to do with whatever one has got.
4. I have got some plots of best fit curves in terms of RMSE etc. both using NLS and GA. I observe that the NLS has a better fit with past data than GA while the GA is able to forecast the future better. The reason to me is unclear. I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance regarding this. Is there any statistical test of significance of the parameters obtained in GA using R, knowing that they should ideally satisfy the normal distribution?
5. I am trying to think about the penalty, but the magnitude of that will have to be based on some theory, and I cannot find any.

Comment: there are a bunch of issues with this question that will have to be resolved before it can be answered. (1/2) Your first question sounds like an optimization issue, which we can't really answer without more information and context. Why are you using GA (rather than a deterministic hill-climbing approach) in the first place?  Do you have reason to suspect multiple local optima? If so, your bounds need to encompass *all* of the possible optima, and you need to tune the parameters (population size, mutation rate, run length) to make sure you reliably converge on the global optimum

Comment: (2/2) in some cases there are ways to do inference on computed quantities without making explicit assumptions about the distribution of the outputs ("synthetic likelihood", "likelihood-free inference", "approximate Bayesian computation"), bu they're complicated and do require making other explicit assumptions that you probably don't want to get into. What is your objective function?  To do inference you will need to (probably) compute the local curvature of your goodness-of-fit surface.

Comment: @BenBolker Sir, thank you very much for your answer. [See response in edits to the question - moderator]

Comment: Most likely the GA went to the boundary of your parameter space because it found the parameters near there explain the data better. It's possible you're having problems with local optima, but it's more likely that your data is not enough to constrain the solution well, or the conventional wisdom parameter ranges are wrong. To investigate these possibilities, you should plot the data and also plot the best-fit curves you have gotten from your various methods (nls, ga, etc).

Comment: If you are very confident the parameters should lie in certain ranges, you could apply penalties to the fitness function per the vignette, section on constrained optimization https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html but you should always check whether the fit is reasonable-looking on a plot.

Comment: @Paul: Sir, I have edited my post to answer the points you raised.

Comment: Have you checked whether your code is able to determine correct fit parameters for simulated data? Fix some reasonable values for (a, b, c) and generate points from the resulting curve, and see if your NLS and GA are able to recover the values of (a, b, c).

Comment: The documentation for the GA package is very limited, so it is impossible to tell what the parameters are doing or how to adjust them if there are problems. It is also not a particularly effective algorithm empirically; see Figure 2 of https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v060i06/v60i06.pdf. I would recommend instead using one or more of the top-ranked algorithms in that list, such as GenSA or nlroptr::stogo. This will help you determine if your problem is related to your search algorithm or is a deeper issue with your data.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean when you say that the parameters should satisfy the normal distribution. If you have a single set of data, and those data are generated by fixed values of a, b, c, there is no place for a distribution to be involved. Only if you have many datasets, or if you are interested in the posterior distribution of the parameters, would it make sense to talk about normality of the parameters. What is your actual situation?

Comment: Finally, please show the code which defines the objective function you are optimizing in GA, and the line where you are calling GA.

Comment: @Paul: Thank you sir for replying. 1. I conducted the experiment suggested by you. I found that the code was able to recover (a, b, c).

Comment: 2. 2. GenSA is a simulated annealing algorithm, a methodology I was not familiar with. In the limited time at my disposal, I am trying to learn this methodology and use this. I would inform you of the results as soon as possible. As an aside, what is your opinion of the mcga() package in R? Would I try that?

Comment: 3. Regarding normality: I have only 1 data set.  However, I am trying to test whether b and c satisfy the normality criterion, as I suggested earlier as follows: The parameters b and c are expected to approximate a normal distribution, according to the extant literature. To test this, I have certain ratios of c/b; say =2,4,6. I use an error term for F(t) assuming that the error term follows a normal distribution with variances 0.12,0.18,0.24,0.30.  (...contd.)

Comment: Thus there are 3∗4=12 combinations for the c/b ratio and error variance. I simulate b and c for these 12 combinations using the data I have, using the rnorm() function. I would use this to see whether b and c indeed follow the normal distribution. In this attempt, however, the initial limits set in terms of max and min arguments of the ga() function in R-language again heavily influence the estimates of b and c.

Comment: 4. Objective function: 
f<-function(T, theta) theta[3]*((1-exp(-theta[1]+theta[2])*T))/(1+((theta[2]/theta[1])*exp((-(theta[1]+theta[2])*T))))

Call to GA:
GA2<-ga(type="real-valued", fitness= fitfun, T=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), CS=c(<12 integers separated by commas), min = c(.01, .4, 4000000), max = c(.05, 1, 7000000), crossover=gareal_blxCrossover, maxiter=1000,run=200)

Comment: What is the definition of fitfun?

Comment: fitfun<-function(theta, T, CS) -(sum(CS-f(T, theta))^2)

Comment: @Paul: There have been suggestions that parameters such as elitism and mutation rate have to be tuned. Please guide me as to how to do this if  required.

Comment: Okay, your basic code seems reasonable. Let's jump back to the higher level issues. "Since I used various values for the min and max arguments of parameters in the ga() function, and 2 of a, b and c almost always are close to the limits set, I do not think the parameters near there explain the data better." I don't understand how you can think this. Wherever GA converges to is, by the design of GA, the best fit found so far. If you don't like the GA answer, you have to either try a better search algorithm or question your assumptions about valid parameter range.

Comment: GA is not a particularly excellent technique for real-valued global optimization, despite what your business management literature may have said. And tuning the parameters on a weak algorithm is a waste of time. Just use a better algorithm like the ones I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I am trying to learn SA. So you think that mcga would not be much better?

Comment: The issue with SA is that this is very rarely, if ever, used in business management. No literature to cite.

Comment: Solve your actual problem first, you can figure out later how to make your solution appealing to narrow-minded people, or old people who want their papers and methods cited.

Comment: Sound advice :) Thank you. I would try SA. Thanks for the pointer in this regard.

Comment: mcga doesn't even make the list of good general-purpose algorithms in Mullen's paper (cited above). If you must use something genetic/evolutionary, use genoud. It was the third most reliable in her experiments overall.

Comment: Okay. I would shortly go through genoud.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind help. I would come back on this forum after trying those algorithms.

Comment: @Paul: Sir, I went through the documentation of GenSA and rgenoud here: http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/rgenoudJSS.pdf ; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GenSA/GenSA.pdf

Comment: @Paul: Sir, I went through the documentation of GenSA and rgenoud here: http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/rgenoudJSS.pdf ; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GenSA/GenSA.pdf. I find that there are examples of solutions that optimize a function, but none that estimates parameters in a function given a set of data (my problem that I mentioned initially). I would be grateful to you and the community for guidance on the matter.

Comment: This is not a difficult point. GA is also just optimizing a function, and you have already worked out how to estimate parameters with GA. Why is it so different with GenSA?

Comment: The only difference I can see is that GA is maximizing a function and GenSA is minimizing a function, so when you pass your "fitfun" function to GenSA it should not have the negative sign.

Comment: Sir, I wrote the following code with the consequent error:                           T <- (1:12)
CS <- c(<a set of 12 numbers separated by commas>)
> f<-function(T, theta)  theta[3]*((1-exp(-(theta[1]+theta[2])*T))/(1+((theta[2]/theta[1])*exp(-(theta[1]+theta[2])*T))))
> fitfun<-function(theta, T, CS) (sum((CS)-f(T, theta))^2)
> lower <- c(.0001, .2, 4000000)
> upper <- c(.05, 5, 8000000)
> 
> out <- GenSA(lower = lower, upper = upper, fn = fitfun)
Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "CS" is missing, with no default. Expecting your kind guidance.

Comment: @Paul Sir, I would be grateful if you point out the flaw in the code.

Comment: GenSA probably doesn't know how to feed T and CS to your functions. If you take T and CS out of the function arguments it will just look them up in your workspace. So f<-function(T, theta) should be f<-function(theta) and fitfun<-function(theta, T, CS) should be fitfun<-function(theta)

Comment: For future code issues please just add to your question instead of making a comment, so you can use the proper code block formatting

Comment: @Paul Sir, the code that you modified worked. It is giving very meaningful results. You are my "guru" in this sense. I am in research (PhD) with a chronic health disorder, and the solution to this was elusive. You helped me. Love and respects. Regards to all members of the community.

Comment: @CB_Modeller so glad to hear! Hopefully it moves you toward a good research article or whatever final product you were seeking. Good luck.

Comment: Sir, I tried to solve the same problem by keeping a "holdout" of more points; that is, I used less data than before. I used 7 points instead of 12. However, this time I get an error "Error in f(T, theta) : unused argument (theta)" after using the same code. When I remove theta from the argument, the program stops running. Kindly help.

Comment: @Paul, Sir, If you are around, please help me with regard to the difficulty that I am facing.